# Python - download url and save with generic filename

Tags: python, api, parsing, url, download

I'm trying to download fanart images from fanart.tv api. Therefore I wrote a script to build the api call and collect the URLs. The code might need some clean up but I guess it is functional for now: 
[APICaller.py](https://github.com/sKiLLeSS1986/MViDLibraryToolKit/blob/master/python/APICaller.py)

My problem now is to save the images with that generic filename which is givin within the URL

For example
I call my script with these args:

```
python APICaller.py -a "Madonna" -p "C:/temp" -n "Madonna - Hung up"
```

As a result I receive:

```
 'http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/music/79239441-bfd5-4981-a70c-55c3f15c1287/artistbackground/madonna-4fe25d4f1b951.jpg', 'http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/music/79239441-bfd5-4981-a70c-55c3f15c1287/artistbackground/madonna-4fe2766aac587.jpg',
```

... and so on

Now I want to save all images to /extrafanart/madonna-4fe25d4f1b951.jpg ...

What is the best way to handle it? urlparse, split or parsing with regex maybe?

Please help, this is very frustrating :(

Comment: It looks like you get back an array in which case you should loop over the results and download them individually OR you could pick the first element in the array. Can you clarify what you exact input is after your API call and your expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. You mean if I know what the response will look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import urllib
for url in urllist:
    filename = url.rstrip('/').rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.sep, 'extrafanart'), filename)
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, path)
```